# How to filter out useless messages in `bash` shell by default?

Tags: bash

Is there any way to filter out absolutely useless messages in bash session by default?

For example, I would like to never see this absolutely useless message: `Binary file ... matches` while running `grep ...`. It's extremely hard to type something like `grep ... 2>/dev/null` each time, especially considering how often I need to run this command. Besides it will filter out useful messages as well and this is unwanted.

What I would like to see, is some sort of file in `/etc` where I could put a bunch of regular expressions of the useless messages line by line. This filter must apply to `tty` only, i.e. redirected output must stay untouched!

Comment: ... or don't grep in binary files

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to play with your stderr, but there are a number of issues that make that undesirable. For example:

```
exec 2>/tmp/errorfile
```

will put all the STDERR output in the errorfile. You could start a

```
tail -f /tmp/errorfile | grep -v 'Binary file' &
```

in your .bashrc to get the other messages as well. You will see some funny side effects; for example I found that the prompt is written on STDERR.

You will probably have to create a more elaborate command than the tail|grep to filter-out the undesirable messages and do something about your prompt as well. And you might need to clean-up your errorfile as well.